# can I make apache mod_security log file to desired format?

Tags: apache2, mod-security

I am trying to save FULL Apache logs (including all request/response headers with the help of Mod_security) to Elasticsearch.

Currently I am using Filebeat and Logstash to transform the log into a desired format. However if it is possible to make audit log the way I want, there is no need for Logstash and I can make filebeat to save the log directly into Elasticsearch.

So, the question is "Can I change Mod_security audit log's format, so that I won't use Logstash?"

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, this is meant to be a friendly advice. Your question is not related to logstash so tagging it might discourage apache2 users to try and help you. I came to help in logstash but this is not related and I don't know apache. I hope you find the right man for your question.

Comment: @MrSimple I will remove logstash from tag. Thanks :-)